# How to run code when exactly 4 digits/letters have been entered in a edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

How do i make some code run when exactly 4 digits/letters have been entered in a edittext?

Comment: You're going to have to clarify what you mean by "make some code run". Are you wanting to validate that exactly four characters have been entered? Are you trying to trigger an action when the fourth character is entered? Are you wanting to do one action if there are four characters when a button is pressed and a different action for anything other than four?

Comment: Just to add to this, keep in mind that your users will be typing on a touch screen, which is in my opinion a HORRIBLY inaccurate method of typing. So it's a possibility they may type the wrong fourth number and want to correct it. If the code runs automatically, that could lead to frustration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you would need to do is add a TextWatcher to your edittext.

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
  if(messageText.getText().length() == 4){
    //call a function here
  }
}
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked perfectly. Now when the user has entered the 4th digit, a function is called to check if the digits are correct. As kcoppock said i made it so that the user can still edit if entered wrong, so nobody will be annoyed here :) Thanks.